# Explain one recursive function in python

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.x

Here is a recursive function in python3. I have a feeling that I do not fully understand the `if` `else` logic in return statement.

```
items = [3,5,8,6,1,2,10]

def sum(items):
    head, *tail = items
    return head + sum(tail) if tail else head
```

Please explain what is going on in `return` statement.

Comment: -1 Was the title a question, or an order?

Comment: recursive, _adj_: See _recursive_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you're being confused by the `*tail` part of the whole thing:

```
>>> items = [3,5,8,6,1,2,10]
>>> head, *tail = items
>>> head
3
>>> tail
[5, 8, 6, 1, 2, 10]
```

Now, what's happening is this, when you reach the end of the list, as in there's only one item in the list `*tail` returns an empty list:

```
>>> items = [3]
>>> head, *tail = items
>>> head
3
>>> tail
[]
```

In that case, the function just returns the value of `head`.

So, to explain your ternary statement, `(True) if (condition) else (False)`:

```
head + sum(tail) if tail else head
```

Add the head the sum of the rest of the list. So `sum` keeps breaking it down, and then finally hits the base case, which is, if there's only one item in the list, then return the item. [This link](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=items+=+%5B3,5,8,6,1,2,10%5D%0A%0Adef+sum%28items%29%3a%0A++++head,+%2atail+=+items%0A++++return+head+++sum%28tail%29+if+tail+else+head%0A%0Aprint%28sum%28items%29%29&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=3&curInstr=0) will explain in more detail, how exactly this works.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused by `return {var} if A else B` syntax, looks quite puzzling when used on one line together with return.